# Logout and suspend

Tags: xfce

Is there any way to logout and then suspend in one command in XFCE?

I have tried

`xfce4-session-logout --logout  && xfce4-session-logout --suspend`

But the session cuts out at the first command so the suspend does not run

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to provide `logout` option. The `--suspend` is enough, as said in the [man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xfce4-session-logout.1.html) page it does logout with any of the options.

Comment: when I do only `xfce4-session-logout --suspend` it just locks and suspends, I want logout and suspend

Comment: try replace `...&& xfce4-session-logout --suspend` with `...&& systemctl suspend` then

Comment: still have the same problem with that, the suspend part wont run

Comment: maybe `;` instead of `&&`

Comment: `;` instead of `&&` makes no dfference

Comment: `&` should work

Comment: yes it seems to work with `&` if I swap the order of the commands